Why the % symbol comments also the leading spaces after the newline?
I have this minimal working example (MWE):
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\begin{document}

Foo%
   bar

\end{document}

When I compile the .tex file, I get "Foobar". Why are the spaces before "bar" ignored?
But the real question is:

If I want to remove comments in a .tex file, do I always need
to remove the string starting with %, along with the following
newline and the leading spaces of the next line?

I asked this question because I am trying to develop a tool in Emacs Lisp to interactively clean comments from LaTeX documents sent to me by various authors, which I prepare for publication in specialized journals. I don't want to remove all comments because some of them might contain useful information for formatting (e.g., metadata in the bibliography).

Spaces at the beginning of a line are ignored (except in verbatim parts, of course).

Authors who use % somewhere have their reason to; don't remove them.

@egreg Thank you for your comment, but trust me, after nearly fifteen years of copy-editing, I can assure you that most of the comments left in the papers I receive are there simply because the authors are too lazy to remove the commented parts from their work. I need to remove the comments because many tools that automate the (re)formatting of papers require clean code. However, as I explained above, I do this interactively to evaluate, comment by comment, whether to remove it or not.

You can probably replace in non-verbatim-stuff from and including % up to and including the end of line by a character whose category is 9(ignored). But, afaik, in nowadays' LaTeX 2e no character has category 9 assigned. In Knuth's plain TeX the null-character (^^00 or ^^@ in ^^-notation) has category 9 assigned. But the result will probably not be what you take for clean code.

Alternatively: In case the last thing occurring before % in the line is something that gets tokenized as a control word token, replace in non-verbatim-stuff from and including % up to and including the end of line by a space. In case the last thing occurring before % in the line is not something that gets tokenized as a control word token, remove in non-verbatim-stuff from and including % up to and including the end of line.

In some pieces of code comments should not be removed as they serve a special purpose, e.g., the purpose of preventing characters inserted due to the \endlinechar-mechanism from being processed further.

If you remove ends of lines, this might concatenate several lines or parts of several lines into very long lines...

When TeX begins to read a new line of input, the reading-apparatus is in state N(new line). In state N characters of category 10(space) are ignored/skipped rather than yielding creation of tokens and appending tokens to the token stream. That's why the leading spaces of the line "   bar" are ignored.

E.g., the package docstrip only removes comments that start right at the begin of a line of .tex-input...

@UlrichDiez A lot of infos here! Many thanks! Maybe you could organize your comments in an answer.

Why not remove the text of the comment, but leave the % in place? Will that work for your purpose?

@dedded I'll add this option to my tool. Thanks.

Assuming normal catcodes and \endlinechar, an end of line is a space, and spaces at the beginning of a line are always ignored whether or not there is a comment on the previous line.
Consider
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}


aaa % c1
bbb

ccc% c2
ddd

\LaTeX% c3
eee

\end{document}

To remove the first comment you need to remove from % up to and including the end of line.
To remove the second comment, you also need to remove from % up to and including end of line.
To remove the third comment, you need to remove from % but leave the end of line, or add a space.
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}


aaa bbb

cccddd

\LaTeX eee

\end{document}


Thank you very much, especially for case c3!

As to your main question: leading spaces and multiple spaces are ignored by TeX, regardless of preceding comments. In other words: having one, many or no spaces before "bar" on a new line would not show any difference in the output.
Consequently, as to your real question: other answers are much more complete

your second paragraph is wrong, you need to remove the newline
